# Is there a way of running date formatter on Xcode's playground? Cos it seems type Date() doesn't work in playground

Tags: swift, xcode

Below is the code snipet

Works well on my project xcode project but not on my playground.

```
let todaysDate = Date()       //cannot find 'Date' in scope
print(todaysDate)

func getDayForDate(_ date: Date?) -> String {    //cannot find 'Date' in scope
    guard let inputDate = date else {
        return ""
    }
    let formatter = DateFormatter().         //cannot find 'DateFormatter' in scope
    formatter.dateFormat = "EEEE"
    return formatter.string(from: inputDate)
}
print(getDayForDate(todaysDate))`
```

Answer (score 6):

Try importing Foundation at the top of your playground. It would work.

Just put "import Foundation" on any line in your playground, preferably on line 1 so it doesn't affect the readability of your code.